# Function masks itself causing a conflict in my shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have created a function like:

```
# Wed Sep  1 07:27:54 2021 ------------------------------
# function designed to read data from a specific table from the aws database
#' Read GA Query 2 data from aws
#' @description Read GA Query data from aws. Simple version, without any data reshaping, nor columns subsetting
#' @export
 read_aws_step2_sden1428_ga_q2 <- function() {

  x_dt <- sw.uxdashboard::aws_read_table(table_name = sw.config$step2_sden1428_ga_q2)
  # x_dt is a local variable within this function, so I use name as simple as possible

}
```

and when Im trying to add it to NAMESPACE file with `devtools::document()`

I get this conflict.

Then I try to run my shiny app and get:

```
Warning: Error in : 'read_aws_ux_metrics_step2_sden1428_ga_q2' is not an exported object from 'namespace:sw.uxdashboard'
  47: server [C:/Users/User/Documents/SDEN1428/R/app_server.R#30]
Error : 'read_aws_ux_metrics_step2_sden1428_ga_q2' is not an exported object from 'namespace:sw.uxdashboard'
```

but the function is exported from NAMESPACE I can see it. Any ideas about this mask issue?

[image]

Comment: I don't see `ux_metrics` in the name of your function.

Comment: yes I have added this but still got the same error with ux_metrics in the name.